# Cordova + Angular 4 + GTM (Google Tag Manager) required items?

Tags: angular, cordova, cordova-plugins, google-tag-manager

I have an Angular 4 application, which is built in Cordova (version 8.2.1) for both IOS and Android, and a requirement for analytics using Google Tag Manager (GTM).

I'm hoping that someone can tell me what I need to get this working (Cordova plugins, Angular module, etc.). The Angular 4 app works great, and I have built it on the various mobile devices already. Also, I have a GTM account.

I've seen various posts saying that I need a Cordova plugin, but they are quite old posts, so I'm not sure if that is still the case. There is an "Angulartics" plugin that I've read about, but again I'm not sure if this is the best solution. I'm hoping for something very simple and quick to start seeing my events firing in GTM on a device.